# Order by in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I will explain my problem with sample ddl and data

```
create table foo ( itm text);


insert into foo VALUES  ('ZZZZ8 AAA'),
                        ('YYYY8 BBB'),
                        ('XXXX7 AAA'),
                        ('WWWW GGG'),
                        ('VVVV7 III'),
                        ('UUUU2 GGG');
```

if i execute `SELECT * FROM FOO`

```
itm
text
------------------
ZZZZ8 AAA
YYYY8 BBB
XXXX7 AAA
WWWW GGG    
VVVV7 III
UUUU2 GGG
```

So My question is how to order the result with respect to the last 3 characters (ex. `AAA`,`BBB` etc)?

---

Expected Output

```
itm
text
---------------
ZZZZ8 AAA
XXXX7 AAA
YYYY8 BBB
WWWW GGG
UUUU2 GGG
VVVV7 III
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT itm 
    FROM   foo 
    ORDER BY substring(itm from char_length(trim(itm))-3 for 3)
```

---

[substring and char_length](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [RIGHT function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) in your ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT itm, right(itm, 3)
FROM foo
ORDER BY right(itm, 3) ASC;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8d90b/2)